# Can I initialise a value in a parameterised constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I have this program in which it is giving error. I am not able to undertsand the reason. PLease elaborate

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class room
{
    int length;
    int width;

public:
    room()
    {
        length=0;
        width=0;
    }
    room(int value=8)
    {
        length=width=8;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<length<<' '<<width;
    }
};

main()
{
    room objroom1;
    objroom1.display();
}
```

The error is
call of overloaded function room() is ambiguous.

Comment: your second constructor has a default value for its only parameter. default values are used if no explicit values are given. your compiler does not know whether to use the standard-ctor without parameters or the other ctor with parameter "int value" and default value "8".

Answer (score 3):

The call of constructor in this declaration

```
room objroom1;
```

is indeed ambiguous because **your class has two default constructors**.

According to the C++ Standard (12.1 Constructors)

> 4 A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument.

So this constructor

```
room()
{
    length=0;
    width=0;
}
```

is default constructor.
And this constructor

```
room(int value=8)
{
    length=width=8;
}
```

also is default constructor because it can be called without an argument.

Moreover there is a logical inconsistance because when the first constructor is called data members `length` and `width` are initialized by zero while when the second constructor is called without an argument the data members are initialized by 8.

And moreover the **second constructor even does not use its parameter**!:)

Simply define the second constructor the following way

```
room( int value )
{
    length = width = value;
}
```

And it would be better to declare the data members as having an unsigned integer type. For example

```
unsigned int length;
unsigned int width;
```

Also it is better if function display will have qualifier `const`. For example

```
void display() const
{
    cout<<length<<' '<<width;
}
```

because it does not change class data members.

Comment: Great answer! I didn't even know that this is still called *default constructor*. Wonder how the convention is in C#, I have some reading to do :)

Comment: @InvisiblePanda Yes, in C# the compiler would select the constructor that does not have a parameter.:)

Answer (score 1):

You have a default constructor (the `room()` function), then you have another constructor which takes an `int` with a default value (the `room(int value=8)` function). Now, if you create an instance without passing an argument, *which* constructor should be called? The default constructor or the one with a default `int` argument?

This is what the message about ambiguous functions is about, that you have two constructors that are equally possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have one parameterless constructor and one constructor with a parameter with default value (To clarify this: a default value means that you don't have to specifiy the parameter `value`, and if you don't, 8 is taken. But calling this constructor without arguments then collides with the default constructor). Thus it cannot be decided which constructor to call when you do

```
room objroom1;
```

By the way, I think you want to do

```
room(int value = 8)
{
    length = width = value; // not = 8
}
```

But to fix your problem, you could e.g. set the default value in your default constructor (the one without arguments). It looks like that is a design problem on your part, as your `room` seemingly has 2 "default" values (0 and 8) and you should decide what you actually want to be the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your class definition to this

```
class room {
public:
    // Correct way to initialize class members
    room(int value = 0) : length(value), width(value) {}

    // Correct way to display class members
    friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & out, const room & r) {
        out << r.length << " " << r.width << std::endl;
        return out;
    }
private:
    int length;
    int width;
};
```

and then use it as

```
int main() {
    room objroom1;
    std::cout << objroom1;
}
```